# Dialogflow Messenger V1 not rendering rich response messages

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How can I get [Dialogflow Messenger v1](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger) to display moch response messages, specifically [Quick Replies](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intent.Message.QuickReplies) (a button that sends text when clicked)?

When provided with the below [WebhookResponse (v2)](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#webhookresponse), the Dialogflow Console debugger correctly displays text_1, quick_reply_1, quick_reply_2, text_2

However, Dialogflow Messenger only displays the plain text, i.e. 'text_1 text_2'

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFpGk.jpg)

```
{
  "responseId": "XXX",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "cancel",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "XXX",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "text_1"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "quickReplies": {
          "title": "quick reply title",
          "quickReplies": [
            "quick_reply_1",
            "quick_reply_2"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "text_2"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "XXX",
      "displayName": "XXX"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 1692
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "message": "Webhook execution successful"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was simple as I was using dailogflow custom payload. here are the steps:

1. Open you intent
2. Scroll down & go-to response.
3. Click on "Add response button" then choose "custom payload" option. At below, it will enable the area for code.
4. In that area, add your JSON code. something like:

```
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "info",
        "title": "Info item title",
        "subtitle": "Info item subtitle",
        "image": {
          "src": {
            "rawUrl": "https://example.com/images/logo.png"
          }
        },
        "actionLink": "https://example.com"
      }
    ]
]
}
```

For more rich reply, you can refer code from here: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#rich

Comment: I wasn't clear when I originally asked the question. I intended to ask how to get Dialogflow Messenger v1 to support the Quick Replies message type in the V2 API https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#google.cloud.dialogflow.v2.Intent.Message.QuickReplies

Comment: Are you using API for replies?

Comment: I'm using Webhook response for the replies. https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook#webhook_response

Comment: OK. Actually I am not using webhook but inbuilt custom payload option for quick replies. Check here http://clientdemo.justgreen.in/chatbot/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, it appears Dialogflow Messenger V1 simply doesn't support the Dialogflow V2 API's Quick Replies Message type. As a workaround, I used Kommunicate.io & custom payloads to implement Quick Replies