# Dialogflow messenger is not displaying rich messages in UI, while fullfillment normal messages are displaying bot not suggestion chips

Tags: dialogflow-es

Dialogflow messenger is not displaying rich messages in UI, while fulfillment normal messages are displaying but not suggestion chips.

Comment: I think my this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61619835/dialogflow-messenger-v1-not-rendering-rich-response-messages/62194122#62194122 answer can help you.